# React gets non responsive when data from Django is used to display a Nivo line chart

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, nivo-react

I have been trying to display a nivo line charts using data from my backend (Django). However, when the data is inserted into the nivo line chart, the react window gets unresponsive.

**The backend sends the timestamps and the values like this --**

**Example -- timestamp = "2023-05-12 16:10:53.000000000"**
**Values -- "39.520004"**

```
class AddView(APIView):

    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
    from rest_framework import status
    import json

    @staticmethod
    @csrf_exempt
    def post(request):

        from awsfetch.rpm import rpm
        timestamps, values = rpm()
     
        return Response({"timestamps": timestamps, "values": values})
```

**This is the nivo chart component --**

```
import { ResponsiveLine } from "@nivo/line";

const MyResponsiveLine = ({ data }) => (
  <ResponsiveLine
    data={data}
    margin={{ top: 50, right: 160, bottom: 50, left: 60 }}
    xScale={{ format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%Z", type: "time" }}
    xFormat="time:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%Z"
    yScale={{ type: "linear", stacked: true, min: 0.0, max: 1.0 }}
    curve="monotoneX"
    axisTop={null}
    axisRight={{
      tickValues: [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
      tickSize: 5,
      tickPadding: 5,
      tickRotation: 0,
      format: "0.2",
      legend: "",
      legendOffset: 0
    }}
    axisBottom={{
      tickValues: "every 1 second",
      tickSize: 5,
      tickPadding: 5,
      tickRotation: 0,
      format: "%S.%L",
      legend: "Time",
      legendOffset: 36,
      legendPosition: "middle"
    }}
    axisLeft={{
      tickValues: [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
      tickSize: 5,
      tickPadding: 5,
      tickRotation: 0,
      format: ".2",
      legend: "CPU",
      legendOffset: -40,
      legendPosition: "middle"
    }}
    enableGridX={false}
    colors={{ scheme: "spectral" }}
    lineWidth={1}
    pointSize={4}
    pointColor={{ theme: "background" }}
    pointBorderWidth={1}
    pointBorderColor={{ from: "serieColor" }}
    enablePointLabel={false}
    pointLabel="y"
    pointLabelYOffset={-12}
    useMesh={true}
    gridXValues={[0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120]}
    gridYValues={[0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500]}
    legends={[
      {
        anchor: "bottom-right",
        direction: "column",
        justify: false,
        translateX: 140,
        translateY: 0,
        itemsSpacing: 2,
        itemDirection: "left-to-right",
        itemWidth: 80,
        itemHeight: 12,
        itemOpacity: 0.75,
        symbolSize: 12,
        symbolShape: "circle",
        symbolBorderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)",
        effects: [
          {
            on: "hover",
            style: {
              itemBackground: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .03)",
              itemOpacity: 1
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]}
  />

);


export default MyResponsiveLine;
```

**My App.js file goes like this --**
so the logic is, when the button is pressed the graph is supposed to be seen in the frontend.

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MyResponsiveLine from "./components/line";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const calculate = () => {
    axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/add/", {})
      .then((res) => {
        const timestamps = res.data.timestamps;
        const values = res.data.values;
        
        const newData = timestamps.map((timestamp, i) => ({
          x: new Date(timestamp),
          y: values[i]
        }));

        setData([{
          id: "Data",
          data: newData
        }]);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-1">
          <button onClick={calculate}>calculate</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style={{ height: "500px" }}>
        <MyResponsiveLine data={data} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried many possible ways to rectify this.. can anyone please help me out?

Comment: How large is the data that is returned from the backend?